# Dictionary of email server settings for different companies and sites?

Tags: email, exchange-server, imap, pop3

Is there a public database of common email settings for different domains for email? Getting Yahoo!, Gmail and others is pretty easy but what if I wanted the IMAP settings from some random company. Is there a good database out there that has a lot of IMAP and POP settings and non-autodiscovery Exchange URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla maintains such a database, see https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailServerList